# Is just the BD_ADDR of responding devices shared with the master during inquiry?

Tags: bluetooth

Is the Bluetooth address exchanged between two Bluetooth devices if no connection is made yet?

As when a device is in discovery mode, and you see for example a tv, headphones, or a different computer show up, is the Bluetooth address of that device being shared with the device making the inquiry, or are the others also getting the Bluetooth address of the inquiring device?

Alternatively, is the Bluetooth address only shared upon selection of the device for connection?

Thanks!

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

Advertising devices broadcast one-way. They do not know what devices have discovered them. Scanning for advertisements is passive. It does not require sending any packets, so neither the advertising device, nor other scanners in the area, will be aware of the scanning device.

Note that Bluetooth addresses are quite complex and varied, so how they are shared is not trivial. [Devices have many kinds of addresses and change what they publicize frequently.](https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/) But to the question of when *an* address (rather than *the* address) is shared, that is during connection.

Comment: Thank you so much, so 1) the exchange of informs is done once a device is selected to connect to? 2) Doesn’t an ID/inquiry packet get sent out by the advertising device so the scanning device knows what to display it as - by name or address or get other info? 3) if another scanner in the area is discoverable, won’t that show -like two phones next to each other scanning will show each other?

Comment: I'm not quite certain what you mean by "the exchange of informs," but after each advertising packet, the advertising device pauses and listens for devices requesting a connection. The advertising packet includes the local name and address, along with advertised services. But scanning is passive; it does not send any packets, so no, two phones that are scanning won't see each other scanning (they would see each other if they are also advertising; you can do both).

Comment: I'm of course simplifying the process. BLE advertising (and communication in general) is quite complicated in its details. For example, an antenna can only send or receive at any given time, not both, and only on one channel (and there are multiple channels to consider). And the BLE antenna is shared with WiFi. So there's a lot of work required to get senders and listeners to actually find each other. If you want to get a primer on some of this, see https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisements-part-1/ or https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-low-energy/ble-advertising-primer/